Summing up values in one column (A) based on if they are conditionally marked (Y/N) in a series of other columns
I am looking to sum up all the values in a column based on if they are marked in a series of other columns. I have created on tibble with numerical representations of each month.
months <- tibble(month = 1:12, count = NA) 

In a separate tibble, I have a sample of five rows that are marked yes or no. The intended goal of this code is to count be able to sum up the count of each month if identfied with a "y" and have that sum be displayed in the original "months" tibble. If the a month is marked with an "n", there is no action. The example here would have a count of 81 for January and 246 for February (40, 125, 81 are marked "y" for February.
  relevant_months<- tibble(count = c(40 ,125, 77, 81, 321), 
                           "1" = c("n", "n", "n", "y", "n"),
                           "2" = c("y", "y", "n", "y", "n"),
                           "3" = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
                           "4" = c("y", "n", "n", "n", "y"),
                           "5" = c("y", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
                           "6" = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
                           "7" = c("n", "y", "y", "n", "y"),
                           "8" = c("n", "y", "y", "y", "n"),
                           "9" = c("n", "y", "n", "n", "y"),
                           "10" = c("n", "n", "n", "y", "n"),
                           "11" = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
                           "12" = c("y", "y", "n", "n", "n"))

The intended goal of the code would be to perform this count summing conditionally based on the identifiers in each month column, and then the total for each month to be displayed in the initial tibble.

Somthing like this?
relevant_months %>% 
  gather("month", "flag", -count) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count * (flag == "y")), .by = "month")


Hi Jacob! Just noting the tidyr::gather() function in R has been superseded by the tidyr::pivot_longer() function (it still works of course, but is outdated - see comments here)

You could use tidyr::pivot_longer and conditional summing:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

relevant_months %>%
  pivot_longer(-count, names_to = "month") %>%
  summarize(count = sum(count[value %in% "y"]),
            .by = month)

Output:
   month  count
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 1        81
 2 2       246
 3 3         0
 4 4       361
 5 5        40
 6 6         0
 7 7       523
 8 8       283
 9 9       446
10 10       81
11 11        0
12 12      165


library(tidyverse)



mysum <- ( 
  
    relevant_months
    %>% summarise(
        across(everything(),
           ~ (function (var,val) {
                
               if (var!='mycount'){          
           
                 sum(ifelse(val=='y',mycount,0), na.rm = TRUE) 
               } else NA
              })(cur_column(), .)
        )
    )
  )


rbind(
  relevant_months,
  mysum
)

t(mysum)

Result:
# A tibble: 6 x 13
  mycount `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`   `10`  `11` 
    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1      40 n     y     n     y     y     n     n     n     n     n     n    
2     125 n     y     n     n     n     n     y     y     y     n     n    
3      77 n     n     n     n     n     n     y     y     n     n     n    
4      81 y     y     n     n     n     n     n     y     n     y     n    
5     321 n     n     n     y     n     n     y     n     y     n     n    
6      NA 81    246   0     361   40    0     523   283   446   81    0    
# ... with 1 more variable: `12` <chr>

        [,1]
mycount   NA
1         81
2        246
3          0
4        361
5         40
6          0
7        523
8        283
9        446
10        81
11         0
12       165

